# Unable to get i2c working

Tags: i2c

I have a Raspberry Pi 3, am reasonably new to the RP, and have tried to get the RP talking to an i2c slave device using Node-Red, nodejs, and python, but without success. The device works perfectly when connected to an 8-bit MCU.

The strange thing is, when I run i2cdetect -y 1, the device is detected, yet when I attempt to run i2cget, the same byte value is returned, irrespective of the device register address I attempt to read. The byte value is also equal to the last value I sent to the device using an i2cset command.

If anyone with experience using i2c on the RP can assist, this will be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
import smbus 
import time 

bus = smbus.SMBus(1) 
addr = 0x67 

def readbyte(): 
    val1 = bus.read_byte_data(addr, 0) 
    return val1 

while True: 
    val2 = readbyte() #this returns the value as a byte between 0 and 255. 
    print val2 
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: ...and the device is?  The Python script you used will also be useful.

Comment: ..an LT power monitor. As mentioned, it works perfectly with C code.

I'm not familiar with python, so I change values in the python code and rerun it.

I seem to have an issue formatting the code, here it is anyway
import smbus
import time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
addr = 0x67

def readbyte():
        val1 = bus.read_byte_data(addr, 0)
        return val1

while True:
        val2 = readbyte()      #this returns the value as a byte between 0 and 255. 
        print val2
        time.sleep(1)

Comment: Edit new information into your question, not the comments.

Comment: I believe it should be obvious that that is not what I am attempting to achieve. As mentioned, the C code runs on an 8-bit device I would like to have the option to use node or python on the Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: I know this is besides the point but if you're "not familiar" with python why don't you just stick with C?  More on point: If you have an example in C that works and one in python that doesn't, it would be good if you posted a minimal version of each.  And as joan points out, please edit information into the question; like S.O. we aren't a discussion forum.  There are enough people around here with "experience using i2c on the RP" but we probably aren't inclined to drag stuff out of you if you can't be bothered to be more specific in describing the details of your problem.

Comment: Can you share * the part number/datasheet of the device you are using. my googlefu turns up [this](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/2945fb.pdf). is the same one you are using ? * share the "C" code that **works** ? it would be useful to compare it with your python program.

Comment: noob, learning. Be nice.

Comment: @goldilocks - I am not yet familiar with RPi and Linux. Does the information I provided not indicate that the issue points to something amis with my installation on the RPi rather than an issue with details of i2c implementation?

Comment: @Shreyas - that is the device I have connected. I do not believe the issue is with C implementation of i2c, or implementation specific to
a particular manufacturer's part, I believe it relates to i2c on the RPi, on Linux.

Comment: This post relates to my unfamiliarity with the RPi and Linux, and am looking to learn implementation on the RPi using something other than C, i.e. node js , node-red, python etc. I mentioned that when I run i2cdetect -y 1, the device is detected, yet I am not able to explain why i2cget is not working as expected. 
Perhaps I should have been a little more specific in my initial question, and phrased it as follows.
What is a good, repeatable approach toward installing Jessie and any additional requirements and i2c tools on the RPi to ensure reliable operation of i2c on the platform?

Comment: *"Perhaps I should have been a little more specific in my initial question, and phrased it as follows..."* -> That is kind of the problem.  Information like that is already available online, so you would just be asking people to repeat things you've likely already seen so you can cherry pick among them ([see here about that](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/794/5538)).  This is instead why we expect the person who *asks* make an effort by explaining *in detail* 1) What you tried to do and how you tried to do it; 2) What you expected to happen; 3) What actually happened.

Comment: You may not recognize it (all apologizies I seem aggressively accusatory -- what I think you are new to is more the process than the subject matter), but what you did initially is *summarize* rather than explain in detail the problem.  The problem with that is there are too many points where people commonly make simple mistakes that are ambiguous or hidden in their summary.

Comment: So, even when you *know for certain* you've done something the reasonable/correct way, if it is pertinent to the outcome, you should make that part plain both to spare everyone else time thinking and asking about it, and you having to go through a back and forth "Yes I did that, yes I know that" -- just say right out what you did.  An internet classic worth glancing through: [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Part 0 : Assumptions & Disclaimers

- Freshly baked (flashed ;p) microsd card containing the latest raspbian distro (jessie as of this writing)
- RPI 3
- kernel version > 3.18 (`uname -a` should tell what is the running kernel's version)
- below instructions taken from from [adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c) 
  solely for guiding new folks (and my own reference), no malice intended in any way

### Part 1 : Setup

- Installing the required packages
- python support for smbus

`sudo apt-get install python-smbus`

- i2c debugging tools

`sudo apt-get install i2c-tools`

- Enabling kernel support (i2c is off by default) using raspi-config
- raspi-config -> advanced options -> A7 i2c -> arm i2c interface enable (yes)
- raspi-config -> advanced options -> A7 i2c -> load i2c kernel module by default (yes)
- reboot
- Enabling device tree overlay

`sudo nano /boot/config.txt`

- Append the following lines

`dtparam=i2c1=on`
`dtparam=i2c_arm=on`

- reboot

### Part 2 : Verification

- use i2cdetect to check if the device is detected

`sudo i2cdetect -y 1`

detected device are indicated with addresses that are not `--`

### Part 3 : Connecting LTC2945

There is a rather long discussion on the raspberrypi forum [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=129372) 
on the topic of connecting to LTC2945.

Here is the extract that is probably most relevant to the question at hand

> by joan » Sat Dec 19, 2015 10:47 am
>
> > munnik wrote:
> >     ...
> >
> > > I2C Interface
> > >       The LTC2945 includes an I2C/SMBus-compatible interface to provide access to the onboard registers. Figure 5 shows a general data transfer format using the I2C bus. The LTC2945 is a read-write slave device and supports the SMBus Read Byte, Write Byte, Read Word and Write Word protocols. The LTC2945 also supports extended Read and Write commands that allow reading or writing more than two bytes of data. When using the Read/Write Word or extended Read and Write commands, the bus master issues an initial register address and the internal register address pointer automatically increments by 1 after each byte of data is read or written. After the register address reaches 31h, it will roll over to 00h and continue incrementing." A Stop condition resets the register address pointer to 00h. The data formats for the above commands are shown in Figures 6 to 11.
> >
> > So I would guess that my original code in this post should work as expected? Is this a bug in the Linear device, I'm not an I2C expert so I'm not sure.
>
> From memory it's more of a bug in the Pi's I2C software driver.
>
> The problem is the handling of repeated starts.
>
> The driver is sending start address (0x6F) write (5) stop start address (0x6f) read ... stop, it needs to send start address (0x6F) write (5) start read ... stop.
>
> From the Linear datasheet "A Stop condition resets the register address pointer to 00h.". It's that superfluous stop which causes the problem.
>
> The I2C module does have a combined flag which you can try setting. That is meant to permit repeated starts. I have not had reliable results when I tried using it, quite possibly my mistake.
>
> by munnik » Sat Dec 19, 2015 12:09 pm
>   Great! I switched back to SMBus after:
>
> `echo -n 1 > /sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/combined`
>
> and now everything works fine, even setting the MAX and MIN values which failed before. PROBLEM SOLVED, thank you very much for your help!

### Part 4 :

- If the above works, thank @joan for her help :)

### Notes

- if you spot any errors or omissions, leave me a comment and I will try to address it as soon as possible

Comment: thanks for the very helpful heads up on the LT part issues, which indicates that this may not be a RPi / Linux issue after all. I will follow your instructions on a fresh install, and hook up an i2c rtc or similar in order to verify the i2c operation.

Answer (score 1):

I2C is real easy to use.
If you can detect the device, it means it's communicating with the Pi.
if you are looking for any specific code please specify else you can find hundreds [I2C sample code over here](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity).

Comment: Here, check out what @Joan has:  http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for but the only guide I could find that worked perfectly when I was setting up an RTC was the one at Adafruit.

Try searching for Adding a Real Time Clock to Raspberry Pi - Adafruit pdf